# Should I create a new quartz job and trigger or one job and many triggers?

Tags: java, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

I am looking to use quartz to schedule emails, but I'm not sure which approach to take:

1. Create a new job and trigger whenever an email is scheduled OR
2. Create a single job, and create a new trigger each time an email is scheduled

I need to pass the message/recipient etc either way, and I'm not sure whether creating heaps of jobs will start adding considerable memory overheads, as there will quite possibly be thousands of emails scheduled.

**Update**: These emails will be scheduled by users, not by me - so I will be adding these programmatically at runtime, they aren't scheduled to go out at any particular time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quartz is intended to handle tens of thousands of triggers. The main limit to scalability here is the space available in your JobStore. A JDBCJobStore backed with a reasonable database should be able to handle hundreds of thousands of triggers.

If a single job can be parameterized through the trigger's job data map, create a single job and one trigger for each email. Quartz polls the job store periodically to look for triggers that are ready to fire. Quartz is designed to safely handle arbitrarily large result sets from this query.

What matters—and this really has nothing to do Quartz itself—is that you have the necessary bandwidth to execute peak loads. If users tend to schedule mails in clumps, you need to make sure that you have the computing resources to get the emails out. This would include network bandwidth, processing, and enough worker threads configured to utilize the available resources.

Note that you can configure what Quartz should do with a trigger if it does get too far behind in executing jobs. You can keep trying, skip the trigger, etc.

Comment: Hi Erickson, It will be configurable via the trigger's jobDataMap, (which I didn't realise existed), so I'm going to go with this way of doing things.

I'll be setting the trigger to keep trying if it fails - can't miss out emails just because another one is being generated at the time...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are the triggers to be based on a time schedule? You can use a [CronTrigger](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/CronTriggers%20Tutorial.html) to set up a more complex time based schedule rather than individual triggers.

Comment: They will be on a time schedule, but these are different emails to different people, so having the trigger fire more than once isn't really going to accomplish much.

Comment: Just read the update. Doesn't that mean that you will have to create multiple triggers anyway (at runtime)? As many users can make different schedules?

Comment: Yep - there will be lots of triggers, but I was wondering if it was better to try and and reduce the number of jobs, so lots of triggers for a single job.

Comment: As long as the job that is being performed is always the same, and the variables can be collected dynamically, yeah, you should be able to.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider queuing or otherwise grouping a set of emails and have a single, or maybe a few, periodic (or scheduled) job(s) that then takes care of the 'batch'.

You could even have the Quartz job queue the emails for a collection of workers to consume and send.

I would not recommend thousands of Quartz jobs/triggers - it just isn't the intended use of the tool (IMHO).

---

EDIT: In response to the comment below:

I would not recommend thousands of Quartz jobs/triggers when used as part of a framework executing an application in the same JVM, The jobs/triggers will be competing for resources with the rest of the application.

Comment: "Quartz can be used to create simple or complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks are defined as standard Java components or EJBs." -- Quartz Home Page

Comment: The authors of Quartz do recommend using it for hundreds of thousands of jobs. Twisting tools into roles they weren't designed for is one of my pet peeves, as it always leads to trouble. But in this case, Quartz was expressly designed to scale in this way.

Comment: I think we're closer to agreement than it may appear.  Quartz, running on its own can handle as many jobs/triggers as you want to throw at it.  When used in an application framework, I don't want it competing with the Web application for resources, so I'd limit the number of jobs/triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend one job and one trigger.  Put the email requests in a database table and have the quartz job look for new emails to send.